# Localizando valores em um python array e atribuindo valores específicos

Tags: array, python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
posicao = [47, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 68, 87, 63, 78]
```

Preciso procurar nesse vetor os valores [24, 18].

Após localizar todos, preciso atribuir nessas posições, um valor aleatório, porém IGUAL.

Estou tentando de várias formas, mas não consigo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato aos que puderem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esse caso o valor aleatório é gerado no inicio e apenas uma vez, que será então aplicado em todas as substituições. Estas podem ser feitas com base numa lista de valores a substituir, e percorrendo as duas, com um duplo `for`:

```
import random

posicao = [47, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 68, 87, 63, 78]
aleatorio = random.randrange(0,200)

for j in range(len(posicao)): #percorrer a lista original
    if posicao[j] in [24,18]: #ver se o elemento se encontra nos que se quer trocar
        posicao[j] = aleatorio #fazer a troca
```

Outra solução é utilizar o método `index` do array para achar o elemento. E apesar de ser mais simples lança uma exceção se o elemento não existir, que neste caso seria se o elemento que quer colocar o aleatório não existir no array `posicao`.

Controlando já essas exceções ficaria desta forma:

```
import random

posicao = [47, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 68, 87, 63, 78]
aleatorio = random.randrange(0,200)

for i in [24,18]: #valores a colocar o mesmo aleatório
    try:
        posicao[posicao.index(i)] = aleatorio
    except:
        pass
```

**Edit**

Para uma busca e substituição por índices pode fazer:

```
import random

posicao = [47, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 68, 87, 63, 78]
aleatorio = random.randrange(0,200)

for i in [2, 3, 10, 11]: #indices a substituir aqui no for
    posicao[i] = aleatorio
```

Comment: Acredito que a primeira forma possa ser otimizada. Fazendo o `for` em `i`, você percorrerá toda a lista duas vezes, porém, se você trocar o `if` interno para `if j in [24,18]`, o `for` em `i` não será necessário, percorrendo a lista apenas uma vez. Outra possível mudança seria trocar o `range(len(posicao))` por `index, value = enumerate(posicao)`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss concordo que a nível sintático o `if j in` que disse seja de facto mais optimizado e já troquei a resposta para tal. Mas a menos que a implementação do `if x in colecao` não seja O(n) como eu penso que é, continua a ser um algoritmo quadrático, O(n^2). Simplesmente uma das pesquisas lineares está feita à custa desse `if`. Naturalmente daria para transformar o algoritmo num com custo O(nlogn) ou mesmo O(n) mas implicaria alterar a estrutura dos dados originais para uma arvore ou tabela de hash respetivamente.

Comment: Muito, Muito Obrigado! Pela ajuda.

Comment: Desculpa perguntar novamente, mas se eu, ao invés de buscar os valores [24, 18], busca-se pelos índices deles, no caso [2, 3, 10, 11]. Como ficaria?

Comment: @Danilo já editei a resposta para substituição pelos indices também

Comment: @Isac Muitíssimo Obrigado!